# Incorrect Predictions after exporting file to PMML from R to Python

Tags: python, r, gbm, pmml

I have built a gbm classifier on R using the library gbm.

```
gbm2<-gbm(deal_stage~.,data=train,train.fraction=1,
          interaction.depth=4,shrinkage=.001,
          n.trees=6000,bag.fraction=0.5,cv.folds=5,
          distribution="bernoulli",verbose=T)

r2pmml(gbm2,"/gbm_test.pmml",compact=TRUE)
```

Then on Python, when I try to do predictions from the PMML file, I get different results than what I had on R.

```
from pypmml import Model
model = Model.fromFile('gbm_test.pmml')
model.predict(observation)
```

Overall, I get a different accuracy on the train and on the test set for both models.
My dataset contains integer, and string features. And there are missing values for some fields, which should normally be handled by the classifier.

I would greatly appreciate an advice to see what should I change to make my predictions on Python coincide with what I observe on R!
Thanks!

Comment: Could you open an issue in the github of pypmml? https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml, it's better that you could attach your model and provide the results of one or several observation records using the R model, then pypmml maintainers can reproduce your issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JPMML tools for converting models to PMML files, then you should be also using JPMML evaluators for scoring these PMML files. The JPMML software project has extensive integration test coverage, which covers the whole pipeline.

Right now, will you be getting the correct predictions if you switch from PyPMML to [JPMML-Evaluator-Python](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-python)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am getting the exact same inaccurate predictions as before with JPMML evaluators, so this cannot be the good solution to my problem.

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. For starters, does the mis-prediction affect all/random rows, or rows with missing values only? Does the mis-prediction happen if the dataset only contains integer features? Could be an issue with the R2PMML package.

Comment: You're right, I think the issue has to do with the R2PMML package and how it deals with missing values. I will try to find a solution for it!